# Redux updating state using object's id

Tags: redux, react-redux, state

I'm working on an exercise app where a user can input an exercise and a weight. When they do, that name/weight object is also assigned an id. So for example, the state could look like this:

```
[
  {
   movementName: squat,
   movementWeight: 100,
   id: 1
  },
  {
   movementName: bench press,
   movementWeight: 200,
   id: 2
  }
]
```

What I'm having trouble with is updating the weight of a specific exercise and deleting exercises. With the code that I have now, what happens is I get a new object with a new id. For example if I was updating the squat I get:

```
[
  {
   movementName: squat,
   movementWeight: 100,
   id: 1
  },
  {
   movementName: squat,
   movementWeight: 200,
   id: 2
  }
]
```

If I were to delete the squat I would get:

```
[
  {
   movementName: squat,
   movementWeight: 100,
   id: 1
  },
  {
   id: 2
  }
]
```

I know I somehow should use the objects id's to do this, but I don't know how. Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = [];

const movementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_MOVEMENT: 
            return [ 
                ...state, action.payload
            ];
        case UPDATE_MOVEMENT:
            return [
                ...state.map(item => item.movementName === action.payload.movementName ? action.payload : item)
            ];
        case DELETE_MOVEMENT:
            return [
                ...state.filter(item => item.movementName !== action.payload.movementName)
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default movementReducer;
```

My action:

```
export const updateMovement = formValues => async dispatch => {
    const response = await movements.post('/movements', formValues);

    dispatch({ type: constants.UPDATE_MOVEMENT, payload: response.data })
};
```

Any help or tips of where to start would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong here is using movement name to update/delete, you should use movement id instead. Passing the id that you want to update/delete to the reducer. Then you use that id to update/delete inside the reducer.

so your action should be:

```
export const updateMovement = (formValues) => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await movements.put('/movements', formValues);

  // I assume that you can get the updated movement id from the response
  const updateId = response.data.id;
  dispatch({ type: constants.UPDATE_MOVEMENT, payload: { data: response.data, id: updateId } });
};

export const deleteMovement = (deleteId) => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await movements.delete('/movements', deleteId);

  dispatch({ type: constants.DELETE_MOVEMENT, payload: { id: deleteId } });
};
```

and inside your reducer, you get that id to process the state

```
const initialState = [];

const movementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_MOVEMENT:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case UPDATE_MOVEMENT:
      return state.map((item) =>
        item.id === action.payload.id ? { ...item, ...action.payload.data } : item,
      );
    case DELETE_MOVEMENT:
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default movementReducer;
```